# PHP secure login script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I was just wondering how secure my code looked and if I'm overlooking any serious mistakes. Any suggestions/critiques are welcome.

This is my relevant login script.

login.php

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['remember']) && isset($_POST['user'])) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) {
        $past = time() - 100;
        setcookie('remember_me', gone, $past);
    }
}
  require_once 'header.php';

  error_reporting(0);

  if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];
      $hide = sanitizeString($_POST['hide']);
      $userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $now = date('r');



      if ($user === "" || $pass === "" || $hide != "") {
          $error = "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center animated shake'>Not all fields were entered</div>";
      } elseif (!preg_match('~^[a-z0-9_.-]+$~i', $user)) {
          $error = "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center animated shake'>Usernames must be all lowercase. They can only contain letters, numbers, periods, hyphens, and underscores</div>";
      } else {
          $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT pass, user FROM members WHERE user= (?) LIMIT 1");
          $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);

          $stmt->execute();

          $result = $stmt->get_result();
          $num    = $result->num_rows;
          $row    = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

          if (password_verify($pass, $row['pass']) && $row['user'] == $user) {
              $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE `members` SET `logins`=logins + 1 WHERE user= (?)");
              $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);

              $stmt->execute();

              $result = $stmt->get_result();

              $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
              $_SESSION['canary'] = time();
              $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

              $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT logins FROM members WHERE user=(?)");
              $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);

              $stmt->execute();

              $result = $stmt->get_result();
              $num    = $result->num_rows;
              $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

              if ($row['logins'] == 1) {
                  queryMysql("INSERT INTO leave_type (user, hours, leave_start, leave_end, leave_reason, leave_type)
                    VALUES ('$user', '24.00', '2016-01-08T06:30:00', '2016-01-09T06:30:00', 'Example Leave', 'Annual')
                  ");
                  die("<br><br><script>setTimeout(function () {
                              window.location.href='FullscreenForm.php'; // the redirect goes here
                            }, 100); // 5 seconds</script>
                  <div class='alert alert-info text-center animated bounceInDown'>Hi. Since this is your first time logging in Please go to the <a href='FullscreenForm.php'>" .
                  "Edit Profile</a> page and input your information so the app will work correctly. Or just wait and you'll be redirected</div>");
              } else {
                  die("<br><br><script>setTimeout(function () {
                              window.location.href='members.php?view=$user'; // the redirect goes here
                            }, 0); </script><div class='alert alert-success text-center animated bounceInDown'>You are now logged in. Please <a href='members.php?view=$user'>" .
                    "click here</a> to continue.</div>");
              }
          } else {
              //queryMysql("INSERT INTO failedlogins (user,pass,hide,ip,time)VALUES('$user', '$pass', '$hide', '$userIp','$now')");
              $stmt=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO failedlogins (user,pass,hide,ip,time)VALUES((?), (?), (?), (?), (?))");
              $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $user, $pass, $hide, $userIp, $now);
              $stmt->execute();

              $error = "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center animated shake'><span class='error'>Username/Password
                  invalid</span></div>";
          }
      }
  }
```

header.php (on all pages on site)

```
require_once 'functions.php';
error_reporting(0);
$year = time() + 31536000;

if ($_POST['remember']) {
    setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['user'], $year);
} elseif (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    setcookie('remember_me', $_GET['username'], $year);
    echo "
          <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function(){
              //Check if the current URL contains '#'
              if(document.URL.indexOf('#')==-1){
                  // Set the URL to whatever it was plus '#'.
                  url = document.URL+'#';
                  location = '#';

                  //Reload the page
                  location.reload(true);
              }
          });
          </script>";
}
  $params = session_get_cookie_params();
  setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + 60*60*24*3, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);


  session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION['canary'])) {
      session_regenerate_id(true);
      $_SESSION['canary'] = time();
  }
// Regenerate session ID every five minutes:
  if ($_SESSION['canary'] < time() - 300) {
     session_regenerate_id(true);
     $_SESSION['canary'] = time();
}
  //checks if user agent has changed on all page requests and logs out if changed
  if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        destroySession();
    }
  } else {
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
 }

  $userstr = ' (Guest)';
  $phpself = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

  if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
      $user     = $_SESSION['user'];
      $loggedin = true;
      $userstr  = " $user";
  } else {
      $loggedin = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Security

Generally, your code looks secure. Your authentication doesn't seem to contain any giant logic flaws, you mostly use prepared statements, you use bcrypt, etc.

**Unused Security Mechanisms and pieces of code**

Your login does contain quite a bit of code that doesn't seem to be used, which makes it more complex than necessary, which makes it harder to maintain, and thus harder to verify its security.

For example, you have a remember_me cookie, which indicates that you have a remember_me functionality, which would need to be checked for security. But you don't actually have that functionality, just the cookie.

Another example is the failedLogins table. It suggests that you have some form of bruteforce detection / account blocking code. But again, it doesn't seem to be used and thus adds complexity and further attack surfaces.

Yet another example is the odd `setcookie` that sets `$_COOKIE[session_name()]` as `session_name()`. It doesn't seem all that harmful, but also doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Because of all these additional pieces of code that don't do anything, it's hard to see at first glance what pieces of code actually *do* do something. For example, is the user agent check real, or just party implemented as some of the functionality above? [It's real - at least after the request after the initial login - , but it takes extra effort to see that]

**Possible future SQL Injection**

For the most part, you use prepared statements, which is great. But then all of a sudden, you have this:

```
queryMysql("INSERT INTO leave_type (user, hours, leave_start, leave_end, leave_reason, leave_type)
    VALUES ('$user', '24.00', '2016-01-08T06:30:00', '2016-01-09T06:30:00', 'Example Leave', 'Annual')
");
```

Now, you currently do have a regex on the username which would make it impossible to exploit this. But what if your requirements change? What if you want to allow `Bill O'Harris` to sign up as well? You might change that regex, and then be vulnerable.

You should really always use prepared statements, not only most of the time.

**Possible future XSS**

Same problem as above, if the regex changes and `'` is allowed, this is vulnerable to XSS:

```
window.location.href='members.php?view=$user'; // the redirect goes here
    }, 0); </script><div class='[...] <a href='members.php?view=$user'>" .
```

**Misc**

- Even though `remember_me` is currently unused, you should set it as httpOnly in case it is used in the future.
- You regenerate the session ever X minutes, which is good, but it is more important to regenerate it when the session state changes, especially on login (to avoid session fixation with some less common php.ini settings)
- It's good to use `htmlspecialchars` on `PHP_SELF`, but you should ideally use it when actually echoing `PHP_SELF`. If you handle other values like this as well, it will be very difficult to determine which values are safe and which are not (eg is `$user` safe?).
- It doesn't seem that you have any CSRF protection. Even login pages do need it (to easily avoid exploitation of XSS in the user area, and to avoid information leakages by force-login a user into an attackers account).

### Other

**Structure**

You should introduce functions to make your code easier to read, test and reuse. You might also want to add classes, such as a `User` class. Functions may be `User:getByName()`, `User:increaseLoginCount()`, `User:firstLogin()`, `redirectFirstLogin()`, `redirectLogin()`, `failedLogin()`, `checkSessionUserAgent()`, etc.

You should also return early / add guard clauses to reduce nesting (eg `if (!isset($_POST['user'])) { return; }`).

**Naming**

Try to be consistent with your naming.

For example, why is the same thing called `user` when using `POST`, but `username` when using `GET`?

**Formatting**

- Your indentation is inconsistent (2 vs 3 vs 4 spaces), as is your use of spaces (sometimes, assignments are aligned, sometimes they are not).
- You don't need `()` around `?`, it just makes the queries more difficult to read.

**Misc**

- Why is the cookie delete check outside of the big `if`? It's confusing, and you need to check `isset($_POST['user'])` twice because of it.
- The `$row['user'] == $user` check is confusing and not necessary. You just selected `$row['user']` based on `$user`, so it will always be equal.
- "clever" code is never good. I would need to look up / test what `$x != md5($x)` does to understand it. It looks like a bug to me.
- `remember_me` doesn't seem to do anything.
- What's `$hide`?
- Do you really need to count the number of logins? It seems to add two unnecessary queries and quite a bit of unnecessary complexity. You could just add a `isFirstLogin` field to the `members` table and select that when selecting pass and user.
- You never do anything with `failedlogins`.